# ADO Service Hooks (fire on workitem.update) slow / unreliable?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-service-hooks

In my ADO project i have set up some service hooks that fire events to an azure service bus queue.
The service hook is set to fire whenever i update a work item. The connection is working seemingly fine, the messages always go through eventually and i never get any failures. The Test message which ADO can send for you also instantly arrives every time. This leads me to believe the service hook is configured correctly.

However, when i actually go and update a work item, and i expect my service hook to fire. it sometimes takes up to 1-2 hours or longer, sometimes only 5 minutes.

I have also made a service hook that sends the exact same message to a storage queue to eliminate the possibility that it is related to my service bus.

I have tried reviewing the configuration of the service hooks, my service bus connection. I have checked the message that does eventually get sent by the service hook which looks fine.
Additionally i have used the Test message option for each of the service hooks and confirmed that it lands in the correct queue.

Are the service hooks just that slow in ADO?
I expected them to be much faster but maybe i was naive..

Or is there something i can do to optimize their trigger response time

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. Ensure the Service Hook you set up on **Project Settings** page is enabled.

   [image]
2. Open the **`History`** of the Service Hook, if all the recent work item updated events have been listed. Got to check whether the provided SAS Connection String of your Service Bus is correct. Try to change the Connection String between **`Primary Connection String`** and **`Secondary Connection String`**.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you, i did check this and they are both enabled and messages are correctly coming through so no issues there, just painfully slow..
Unfortunately using the secondary connection string does not seem to have made a difference

Comment: @MarcBrejner, Did you check whether the "service hooks slow" issue exsits in your other projects and other organizations which are in different regions?
In addition, from the site [Azure DevOps Status](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history), we can see there are some Availability Degradation events impacting the services in multiple regions within recent weeks. Maybe, the issue also is impacted by the events.

Comment: Ah, i did not know about that status site thank you very much!
And yes, i did try another project, however not another organization. It would make sense if i was just experiencing some of those availability degradation events you mentioned, at the times when i was testing.